# How to Dynamically change the style of a CRichEidt Object?

Tags: mfc, cricheditctrl

Now I created a CRichEdit object, which is in single-line mode, what if I want to change it to multiline style, I wanna do all this in response to a ctrl message such as someone press one push-button.
Thx

Answer (score 0):

A GetWindowLong()/SetWindowLong() combination maybe? Not sure if changing this specific style works though.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ModifyStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xhz2t1c%28v=vs.71%29):

```
richedit.ModifyStyle(0, ES_MULTILINE); // Adds multi-line style
richedit.ModifyStyle(ES_MULTILINE, 0); // Removes multi-line style
```

If it doesn't work, consider adding `SWP_FRAMECHANGED` as third parameter.